# What happens when I delete my answer?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

I know when I delete my answer, that had been downvoted by other users, my reputation is back. I just want to know if someone can still see my answer (that has been deleted by me) if they view that question, because when I visit that page, I can still see my answer, with this `undelete` option.

Comment: I would have thought this was a duplicate, but I can't find the original.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, do you remember the answer?

Comment: Ahah: the duplicate is on [meta.se]: "[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)".

Comment: Those with 10K privileges can see deleted questions and answers.  They're not easy to search for though, so unless they're explicitly bookmarked or favorited, finding them on a whim would be difficult.

Comment: @Niang is there a reason why you wanted to rollback to the first revision of your question?

Comment: @Makoto 10k users might be able to dig up recently deleted answers in the 10k mod tools, but it's rare that anyone would bother wanting to look at those.

Comment: @Niang: do not forget the option of disassociation if you do not want to get the "credit" anymore for your deleted post.

Comment: I found it very unpopular on this forum to delete your own answers. I found myself being unable to ask questions [even now] because of that.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic [so] is not a (discussion) forum, it's a question and answer site.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic You shouldn't have gotten a question-ban by deleting *answers* (unless I am gravely mistaken). Regardless, deleting definitely doesn't help avert such a ban.

Comment: @Cupcake Why did you add [tag:support] to this?  Is it really a support request?  Seems very much like [tag:discussion] to me.

Comment: @Joe the description for the [meta-tag:discussion] tag says "*A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective.*" This is most certainly not "subjective", there is a clear answer to the question of what happens to deleted answers.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps.  I tend to think of [tag:support] as more like requests to *do* something (restore a deleted account, merge an account, etc.), not asking about what something does.  However a brief look at questions in [tag:support] seems to confirm what you say.

Comment: @Joe Pro Tip: when referring to Meta tags, you want to use `[meta-tag:support]`, not `[tag:support]`, because the former links to Meta, wile the latter links to tags on [so].

Comment: @Cupcake Hmm, didn't realize that! I haven't used [meta] much since the split, and obviously [meta.se] didn't work that way... thanks for the tip!

Comment: Erm, new protip needed: why doesn't [meta] work here (like it does on other sites)?

Comment: @Joe it will work on [so]. It doesn't work on Meta itself. You think it would, but it doesn't. It's the same way with `[main]`. That will work here on Meta, but not on [main] itself.

Comment: Huh.  Weird.  [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Users with at least 10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), as well as moderators, can see deleted answers.

You can always view your own deleted answers, regardless of who deleted them.

To see a list of your recently deleted answers, go to the answer tab of your profile page, and then scroll to the bottom:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: but the OP has only 721 rep. How could the OP see the deleted answer to ask this question?

Comment: @Anurag You can see **your own** deleted answers even with 1 reputation.

Comment: @Cupcake Will the deleted answer still show up under the "answer"-section in your profile for yourself then ?

Comment: @moooeeeep that's actually not true, even low-rep users have a link to see their recently deleted posts in their profiles.

Comment: @DatRid I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks! Found it. It says "recent" deleted answers. Sorry that I ask again, but do you know in which time frame "recent" is at SO? Because I definitely know I have some deleted answers where OP changed his question a bit and it wasn't useful anymore - but they don't show up.

Comment: @DatRid I don't know, you might as well search around on Meta or [meta.se], or if you can't find anything, ask another question.

Comment: @Cupcake I already did my research, but I didn't found it, so I thought I ask you. But it's not that important that I will open a answer!